# Ammunition fired from a projectile weapon - does it keep the enchantment the bow has?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage

This rule comes from 3.5 i think. 
Is there a rule that states the same for Pathfinder?

Ammunition fired from a projectile weapon with an enhancement bonus of +1 or higher is treated as a magic weapon for the purpose of overcoming damage reduction. Similarly, ammunition fired from a projectile weapon with an alignment gains the alignment of that projectile weapon (in addition to any alignment it may already have).

My question is, if i activate elemental assult (suli ex) while holding my bow and firing and arrow will i deal the extra 1d6 damage from each shot i do?

My dm will argue that I am no longer in contact with the arrow so it looses its enchantment.

Is there any difference between my elemental assult ex ability and a spell that adds a form of elemental damage to a weapon, in this case a bow?

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, you can apply the *elemental assault* energy damage to your ranged attacks from a bow.**

In general your projectile weapons confer their bonuses to their projectiles.  They do not stack.

> **Ranged Weapons and Ammunition**: The enhancement bonus from a ranged
>   weapon does not stack with the enhancement bonus from ammunition. Only
>   the higher of the two enhancement bonuses applies. Ammunition fired
>   from a projectile weapon with an enhancement bonus of +1 or higher is
>   treated as a magic weapon for the purpose of overcoming damage
>   reduction. Similarly, ammunition fired from a projectile weapon with
>   an alignment gains the alignment of that projectile weapon.

Exceptions may exist, such as the *bless weapon* spell from the Paladin spell list.

However, the general rule doesn't even really matter because the Suli racial trait **Elemental Assault** is a specific rule that overrides the general rule. Let's look at that:

> **Elemental Assault (Su)**: Once per day as a swift action, a suli can
>   shroud her arms in acid, cold, electricity, or fire. This lasts for
>   one round per level, and can be dismissed as a free action. **Unarmed
>   strikes with her arms or hands (*or attacks with weapons held in those
>   hands*)** deal +1d6 points of damage of the appropriate energy type.

From a strict rules as written standpoint, the bow is held in your hands, which satisfies one of the conditions for the damage to take effect. It does not specify a weapon type.  Thus, attacks with that weapon held in your hands deal +1d6 damage of the energy type when you activate this racial trait.

If your GM argues against this, gently remind him that the projectile fired from the weapon is not the weapon, and that damage is applied from the weapon, not the projectile -- i.e., it's the bow's damage dice that you roll, and that's the roll to which you are adding the elemental damage die.